# Detecting if javascript is enabled with hidden form field

Tags: javascript, php, hidden-field

It may seem like a repeat question, but I have not found an appropriate answer in the hundreds of answers about detecting whether or not javascript is enabled.
My home page will have a form that requires a zip code to be entered. If the entered zip code is in more than one county, then the visitor will be returned a page to select their state, and then their county. If they have js enabled I can provide them with a nice dynamic dependent drop-down menu of counties once they select a state. Without js I would have to return another page with the county options. 
The home page doesn't need js. Is there a way to use a hidden field in the zip code entry form that would let the next page know if js is enabled?

Comment: "the visitor will be returned a page to select their state, and then their county". This sounds like they are already triggering a page load. If that's the case, you don't need JS. Use server-side logic. If you want to selectively do one thing or other, look into the <noscript> tag.

Comment: If they have js, then the page would use Ajax to populate a county drop down menu on the same page once a state were selected.

Comment: submit the form as usual, and use JS to intercept it if possible. then you can use an ajax request to signal to the server that JS is indeed active. if you get the normal non-ajax submission, then you know JS isn't working.

Comment: Without js I would have to return a new page with the county options

Comment: @Marc B _That went right over my head. Where could I learn about that?

Comment: just have a plain `<form>`, then attach a javascript onsubmit event handler to it. if JS is active, that handler will trigger, and you can prevent the normal form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden field in the form that contains zipcode and fill it on the homepage with js. Once the form is send you can check if the field is empty which would indicate that js is not enabled and render the result page accordingly.